# window.location.href with $(".confirm").click(function (e) does not return full url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to work out where I'm going wrong with the following code.
My full url is http://localhost:4244/Invoice/PayInvoice?invoicenumber=7069 but var url = window.location.href; only returns http://localhost:4244/

```
<a Class="btn btn-success btn-sm confirm" href="/Invoice/PayInvoice?invoicenumber=7069">Pay Invoice</a>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".confirm").click(function (e) {
            var url = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
            alert(url);
            $("#displayPopUp").show();

            e.preventDefault();

            $(".yesupdate").click(function () {
                $("#displayPopUp").hide();

                window.location = url;
                //$(location).attr('href');
            });
            //if (AcceptPayment()) {
            //    // then redirect to original location
            //    window.location = this.href;
            //}
            //else {
            //    alert("Couldn't do my thing first");
            //}
            //var result = window.confirm("You are about to mark invoice as paid, are you sure?");
            //if (result == false) {
            //    e.preventDefault();
            //}
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the value of url to window.location = url; when .yesupdate is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to navigate to the `href` of the `<a>` element being clicked, you can retrieve that address within the `.click()` handler using:

```
var url = this.href;
```

The lines in your snippet just assign the current `location` back to itself, which will just reload the page.

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

```
window.location = url;
```

---

You may also need to remove previous `click` handlers from `$(".yesupdate")` to avoid them stacking from multiple `.confirm`s.

You can use [namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) to target certain handlers.

```
$('.yesupdate').off('.confirm').on('click.confirm', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign to `window.location`, it is [a read-only instance of a Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). Depending on your browser, this may or may not work or throw.

Instead, you should call [`window.location.assign(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.assign) with the URL you would like to navigate to. You can use a full URL with query string and other parts.